# Cast everything to any, what can possibly go wrong?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm upgrading my react typescript codebase due to security reasons, and the most common problem I face is incompatible type due to various things.

Since I have to do it quickly, I'm avoiding type errors by replacing them with `any` every time I face type error issues. I already tested it and it works normally.

Is it okay to do that? What kind of problems I might face in the future?

Comment: You won't  have proper type information around and not know what type of objects you pass around. Yes, you can work without proper types but then you are not really using *Type*script anymore, you won't get any of the benefits.

Comment: can you explicit few type errors that you are afraid spending time with? Since it's an upgrade, did you do any impact analysis, how much is the impact solely due to types? Programming with `any` is almost as good as writing things in `Javascript` most of the time.

Comment: And how ***quickly*** is exactly the **quickly**? A day, couple of hours, minutes .... how much are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Using "any" everywhere makes you not use the features of TypeScript at all, but it will work properly.

The intended solution is to fix the type errors, since they show you what types do not match together and might bring you problems in further development.

Comment: I don't agree about the "but it will work properly". Ignoring typing errors may very well just hide bugs that were introduced by upgrading dependencies.

Comment: I meant it will not add any additional bugs. It will work just as before.

Answer (score 0):

> upgrading my react typescript codebase due to security reasons, and the most common problem I face is incompatible type due to various things

Key is: what are the exact validation failures? What if the library you're using has changed the argument types or order in some function? The failing typing validation is a great warning for using the wrong function signature; ignoring that means you're ignoring a bug in your code. Combined with your "due to security reasons" I'd say that's a bad idea.